# ANCS : what is the concept of PositiveAction?

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

I'm trying to work with the Apple Notification Center Service to make interactions between a Bluetooth peripheral and an iOS device.
In the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/AppleNotificationCenterServiceSpecification/Specification/Specification.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013460-CH1-SW61) Apple mention the 2 notification actions: EventFlagPositiveAction and EventFlagNegativeAction…

So far, the *Negative* part works: once the notification is transmitted to the peripheral, this latter one can trigger the negative action, resulting dismissal of the notification.

But I cannot trigger the *Positive* side of the force... My Notification has a single action button and I want this button to be considered as the positive action... But I don't know how it works: is it implicit ? do all actions have the *positive* flag ? or should I do something to make it recognized as the *positive* one ?

This is more a conceptual question about ACNS, but for information, below is the code I'm using:

1st to register for the local notification in the AppDelegate:

```
    let notificationTypes = UIUserNotificationType.Alert.union(UIUserNotificationType.Sound).union(UIUserNotificationType.Badge)

    let launchAction = UIMutableUserNotificationAction()
    launchAction.identifier = "LAUNCH_ACTION"
    launchAction.title = "OK"
    launchAction.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationMode.Foreground
    launchAction.destructive = false
    /* this is this UIMutableUserNotificationAction that I want to trigger from my external device, and should be considered as the famous positive action I am looking for */

    let notificationCategory = UIMutableUserNotificationCategory()

    notificationCategory.identifier = "LAUNCH_NOTIFICATION"
    notificationCategory.setActions([launchAction], forContext: .Minimal) 
    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: notificationTypes, categories: NSSet(array:[notificationCategory]) as? Set<UIUserNotificationCategory>))
```

And 2nd, later to create a notification

```
    let localNotification:UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()
    localNotification.alertAction = "Hello"
    localNotification.alertBody = "World"
    localNotification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 5)
    localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
    localNotification.hasAction = true
    localNotification.category = "LAUNCH_NOTIFICATION"
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so then I have had the answer for my question from Apple developer technical Support.
Posting this here, hopefully this will help someone else:

> the first thing to understand is that “Positive actions are only wired up for telephony related notifications (incoming call, missed call, and voicemail).  There is currently no way to pass through the positive action for an app alert.

Things are easier to understand now…